# Convert.ToChar() failed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to find out the character from an integer value, so I applied `Convert.ToChar()` function.

But `Convert.ToChar()` function fails here

```
char S = Convert.ToChar(151);
```

Why 151 is not converted into character ? It gives 151 only not character.
Is there any other method which converts it into character ?

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: Which version of C# are you using ?

Comment: What character did you expect? 151 is 97 in hex, and corresponds to [this codepoint](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=0097) END OF GUARDED AREA, which doesn't seem like it's printable.

Comment: Where do you see that 151? The debugger would show the character as 151 (since it's unprintable). `ToString` would not print it or print `?` (again, it's unprintable). Keep in mind that `char` is just an integer - to show it anywhere, you need to convert it to string (to show it as text). Also, `Convert.ToChar(int32)` interprets the integer as Unicode; it seems like you're expecting `151` in your local encoding - you need to use the `Encoding` class for that. You might have gotten confused since for 7-bit numbers, Unicode maps to ASCII (e.g. `Convert.ToChar(0x61)` gives `'a'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be trying to convert an ANSI code page 1252 character value (code page 1252 is the default Windows code page for Latin One countries, i.e. most of Western Europe and all the anglophone countries).

If this is the case, then the actual character will be `—` which is the character with code 151 in the 1252 code page. You will need to convert it by putting the ANSI value(s) into a byte array and then using `Encoding.Default.GetString()` to convert it to Unicode:

```
byte ansiValue = 151;
string result = Encoding.Default.GetString(new[] {ansiValue});
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This outputs:

> -

Note that this assumes that your local code page is indeed the correct code page. If you are in a different locale, you'd need to create the specific code page encoding like so:

```
byte ansiValue = 151;
string result = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(new[] {ansiValue});
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, it'll return a character starting from its Unicode value:

```
var x = char.ConvertFromUtf32(151);
```